# What is the meaning of 「こわあてかなわんで」?

Tags: expressions, dialects

Before the expression is said by a guy, he previously says the following sentence. I'm not sure if it is related to Kansai dialect.

しっかりしてんかいな　ほんまに　無｛む｝計｛けい｝画｛かく｝なことされるのいちばんきらいや。

Another question: Does the 「無計画なことされるの」　mean something not being planned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is unmistakably Kansai.

「こわあてかなわんで」, in Standard Japanese, would be:

「怖{こわ}くて敵{かな}わないよ」. = ***"I'm scared shitless!"***

「敵わない」 = "unbearable", "beyond one's power", "can't do", etc.  Remember this word because you will keep encountering it.

Moving on..

「無計画{むけいかく}なことされるの」

「の」＝「こと」.  It is a nominalizer, nominalizing the verb phrase 「無計画なこと（を）される」.

「される」, of course, is the passive voice form of 「する」.

***"getting haphazard stuff done to me"***